# Is it okay to do the next class?

Tags: json, vb.net, class

Deserialization throws me an exception in the part

```
Path 'access', line 1, position 10.
```

I have part of the code like this

```
            Dim lstPyp As List(Of access) = Nothing
            lstPyp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of access))(strRespuesta)
```

The json is this

```
{
    "access": "granted",
    "last_login": "2022-04-07 10:30:07",
    "last_access": "2022-04-07 11:55:01",
    "uid": 5497,
    "user": "pepe",
    "id_comitente": 30,
    "profile": "comitente"
}
```

I have the class as follows

```
Public Class access


    Public Property access As String
    Public Property lastlogin As Date
    Public Property lastaccess As Date
    Public Property uid As Integer
    Public Property user As String
    Public Property idcomitente As Integer
    Public Property profile As String

end class
```

It is the first time that I have to do the classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don' t have any list, just one object so try this

```
Dim pyp As access =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of access)(strRespuesta)
```